# $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(x)=\sin (1/x) , \forall x >0 ; f(x)=0 , \forall x \le 0$ , is the graph of $f$ connected in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Consider the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(x)=\sin (1/x) , \forall x >0 ; f(x)=0 , \forall x \le 0$ , then $f$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R$ . Is the graph of $f$ i.e. $G(f) :=\{ (x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb R \}$ connected in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Answer (score 3):

We know that $G_{>0}:=\{(x,f(x))|x>0\}$ and $G_{\leq0}:=\{(x,f(x))|x\leq0\}$ are connected. Hence, the only way for $G$ to be disconnected is if the above subsets are clopen. But $(0,0)\in G_{\leq0}$, and every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ intersects $G_{>0}$. It follows that $G$ is connected.